# PrimeNG lazy table override 'first' attribute whenever applying filtering

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to initialize a primeNG table using queryParameters. e.g. http://my-url.com/table?name=Joe&first=20 should display data with name Joe, beginning at the 20th entry

That table use lazyLoading with `[lazy]=true` because of the sheer amount of data my backend can provides. When I initialize my component I read url parameters to apply filtering and pagination.

my-component.html

```
<p-table
  [paginator]="true"
  [lazy]="true"
  (onLazyLoad)="onLazyLoad($event)"
  [lazyLoadOnInit]="false"
  [(first)]="firstItem"
> <!-- ... -->
```

my-component.ts

```
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('tableElement', {static: true}) pTableRef!: Table;

  protected firstItem = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route?.queryParamMap.pipe(first()).subscribe({
      next: (paramMap) => this.initStateFromParamMap(paramMap)
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit called, this.firstItem = " + this.firstItem)
    // manually call onLazyLoad with dummy parameters if no filtering is done.
    // if filtering is done, p-table automatically calls onLazyLoad
  }

  private initStateFromParamMap(paramMap: ParamMap) {
    // note : this code is a just simplification of what is done
    this.lazyLoadingDoneAtLeastOnce = true;
    this.firstItem = firstItem;
    this.pTableRef.filter("Joe", name, 'equals');
    console.log("init finished, this.firstItem = " + this.firstItem)
  }

  onLazyLoad(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    console.log("onLazyLoad called, this.firstItem = " + this.firstItem)
    // load specified data from backend
  }
}
```

output:

```
init finished, this.firstItem = 20
ngAfterViewInit called, this.firstItem = 20
onLazyLoad called, this.firstItem = 0
```

Calling `this.pTableRef.filter("Joe", name, 'equals');` result in firstItem being set to zero, this is the basic behaviour if the user decides to manually apply a filter. However I do not want to reset the firstItem in this case.

Notes:

- Swapping filter initialization and pagination initialization order does not change anything.
- If no filtering is done. `this.firstItem` is not changed after `ngAfterViewInit`
- Many unrelated element of my code have been omitted for readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through PrimeNG Table source code, I've found a boolean attribute named `restoringFilter`, if this is set to true, next filtering won't reset first item.

By the way, calling `filters` trigger a timed out filtering, this is why multiples filtering done sequentially do not trigger multiple call to `onLazyLoad`, this is the same reason filtering (and therefore reinitialization of first item to 0...) was done after ngAfterViewInit.

TL;DR, set restoringFilter to true when restoring filters

```
this.pTableRef.restoringFilter = true;  
this.pTableRef.filter("Joe", name, 'equals');
```

This now works perfectly.